# MSSQL 2012 Splitting Records Into Multiple Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Currently my record are as below. One complete record are split by pipe `|` and data are separate by comma.

```
 123,870503-23-5370,021|456,830503-23-5371,031|789,870103-11-5372,041|654,870501-23-5373,051|321,880503-12-5374,061|987,870803-23-5375,071|109,870508-06-5376,081|174,810503-03-5377,091|509,870103-01-5378,101|687,870501-12-5379,131
```

How to split the record to become:

```
C1  C2             C3         
123 870503-23-5370 021
456 830503-23-5371 031
789 870103-11-5372 041
......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of operation should be done in application layer.

Quick workaround uisng XML to split based on `|`:

```
declare @S varchar(1000) = '123,870503-23-5370,021|456,830503-23-5371,031|789,870103-11-5372,041|654,870501-23-5373,051|321,880503-12-5374,061|987,870803-23-5375,071|109,870508-06-5376,081|174,810503-03-5377,091|509,870103-01-5378,101|687,870501-12-5379,131'
```

Spliting to each column using `PARSENAME`:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
select 
REPLACE(n.r.value('.', 'varchar(500)'), ',','.') As c
from (select cast('<r>'+replace(@S, '|', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as s(XMLCol)
  cross apply s.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r)
)
SELECT PARSENAME(c,3) AS col1,
       PARSENAME(c,2) AS col2,
       PARSENAME(c,1) AS col3
FROM cte;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404652)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦════════════════╦══════╗
║ col1 ║      col2      ║ col3 ║
╠══════╬════════════════╬══════╣
║  123 ║ 870503-23-5370 ║  021 ║
║  456 ║ 830503-23-5371 ║  031 ║
║  789 ║ 870103-11-5372 ║  041 ║
║  654 ║ 870501-23-5373 ║  051 ║
║  321 ║ 880503-12-5374 ║  061 ║
║  987 ║ 870803-23-5375 ║  071 ║
║  109 ║ 870508-06-5376 ║  081 ║
║  174 ║ 810503-03-5377 ║  091 ║
║  509 ║ 870103-01-5378 ║  101 ║
║  687 ║ 870501-12-5379 ║  131 ║
╚══════╩════════════════╩══════╝
```

*Warning:*

Using XML may cause problems when your string contains some characters like `<&'">`.

`PARSENAME` is used to quicky split up to 4 slices. Works only with data that doesn't contain `.` character.

**EDIT:**

Inserting is very easy:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
select 
REPLACE(n.r.value('.', 'varchar(500)'), ',','.') As c
from (select cast('<r>'+replace(@S, '|', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as s(XMLCol)
  cross apply s.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r)
)
INSERT INTO your_table(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT PARSENAME(c,3) AS col1,
       PARSENAME(c,2) AS col2,
       PARSENAME(c,1) AS col3
FROM cte;
```

Comment: First limitation can be over come using `Value` method

Comment: Thank lad2025 for quick replied. Your script are working. Can you expand so I can insert the results into database.

Comment: @SiChiPan use [INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(INSERT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) for that

Comment: Bulk Insert is the fastest loading when you hit high record counts.  XML parsing is good for low volume records but the searching capabilities become a problem when you consistently parse high-volume data.

Answer (score 1):

Another method could be simply export the data to a csv file (you can easily do it through the management studio) and then load that csv file using BULK INSERT by specifying field and record delimiters. Detailed explanation in how to do this can be found here: [bulk insert csv](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)